# scalac: Error: object CharRef in intelliJ 14

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I can successfully compile code from terminal with **mvn compile** command. But when I compile code with intellij 14 I got following error:

```
Error:scalac: Error: object CharRef does not have a member create
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: object CharRef does not have a member create
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.scala$reflect$internal$Definitions$DefinitionsClass$$fatalMissingSymbol(Definitions.scala:1179)
    at ...
```

What could be a reason?

Comment: Is your class path configured correctly? That somehow sounds like a problem of different API versions (different library versions). Could you post some source code?

Comment: Indeed, likely a version mismatch problem: `CharRef.create` was added in Scala 2.11.

Comment: I reimport project, invalidate chaches/restart and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by running **File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart**.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem while trying to work with some Scala examples fro Spark.

Apparently the problem that I was experiencing, was caused by incompatibility of IntelliJ project's Scala version (3.11.7) and Spark Maven dependency (2.10):

```
<dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Once I have changed **spark-core_2.10** to **spark-core_2.11** and rebuilt the project, everything started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My project depends on Scala 2.10 but Scala SDK in IDEA was 2.11. I changed also the SDK to 2.10 and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

My version is IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 and has same issue. My solution is the scala-sdk 2.12.1 change to use version 2.10.4 , It can fixed. Help it can help guys.